# Raster image does not show up in Data View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

I'm a new GIS Student. I created and imported 3 raster files for last week's lab. In our lab this week, we are creating a vector image using the raster data. When I import the 3 raster files, it appears to work with no import error. I cannot see any of the 3 but they are in a layer and in the catalog.

ArcMap 10.2

```
ncols 15
nrows 15
xllcorner 2105000
yllcorner 660000
cellsize 5000
nodata_value -9999
0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 2
2 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 2 2
2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 2 0
2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 1 1 2 0 0
2 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 0
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2
2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 2
2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 2
2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 2 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: have you tried right clicking one of the rasters and using the "Zoom to.." option, or clicking the "Full Extent" globe icon near the top.

Comment: Tried both to no avail :-(

Comment: When you say you imported the rasters, what steps did you take to do this? Was it in ArcCatalog or in ArcMap? When you imported, was there a selection on your data?

Comment: Do the rasters have an assigned coordinate system? If so, what is it? The header info indicates a projected coordinate system, probably state plane (California?).

Comment: State Plane NAD 1927 Colorada Central 0502

Comment: I'm now confused. I imported the ASCII file above to a tif, then converted to a polyline. Worked fine. If you're having problems with the raster, reconvert the ASCII files to rasters. Try a new ArcMap document and/or reconvert to vector.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are zoomed out too far. Did you [Build Pyramids](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m1000000)? You can add them to a Mosaic Dataset, and [Build Overviews](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000088000000). This should help make your rasters visible

Comment: I did try and Zoom Out / Zoom IN to no avail. The  Build Pyramids & Build Overviews are beyond the scope of the class so far. Only the 4 week in an into to GIS.